# Clash of clans war during preparation day?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm a member of the clan but I am not part of a war.

Is it possible to donate troops in clan castle?

Answer (score 4):

If you are not in the war, then you cannot donate to the war defense clan castles.

Comment: Yes. Ben is correct. If you're not active in war you cannot donate to the war defense castles. Which is werd. I wish they would change that in an update...

Comment: Clan is doing preparation day right now and I opted out of the war. Confirmed - I am unable to donate any troops to war bases on the war map.